# Why do packages have imports under __init__.py file?

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

For example in `multiprocessing` package we can import class `Process` using `from multiprocessing import Process`. Why not `from multiprocessing.context import Process` where it really belongs?

In fact, I found that they are the same. Why?

Comment: Could we change the title to *Why do some packages have imports under `__init__.py` file*?  This would be much more search engine friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding imports to `__init__` is usually done to shorten the import paths and define a public interface. `multiprocessing.context import Process` is an internal interface and can change in future without maintaining any backwards compatibility.

On the other hand `multiprocessing import Process` is the documented public interface and won't change to break backwards compatibility.

You could see that [`__all__` under `context.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L8) is empty meaning it has no public interface and you should not import from it in your application as it can change in future without any warnings.

```
__all__ = []            # things are copied from here to __init__.py
```

---

Related section on this from PEP-008:

#### [Public and internal interfaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces)

> Any backwards compatibility guarantees apply only to public interfaces. Accordingly, it is important that users be able to clearly
>   distinguish between public and internal interfaces.
>
> Documented interfaces are considered public, unless the documentation explicitly declares them to be provisional or internal
>   interfaces exempt from the usual backwards compatibility guarantees.
>   All undocumented interfaces should be assumed to be internal.
>
> To better support introspection, modules should explicitly declare the names in their public API using the `__all__` attribute. Setting
>   `__all__` to an empty list indicates that the module has no public API.
>
> Even with `__all__` set appropriately, internal interfaces (packages, modules, classes, functions, attributes or other names)
>   should still be prefixed with a single leading underscore.
>
> An interface is also considered internal if any containing namespace (package, module or class) is considered internal.
>
> Imported names should always be considered an implementation detail. Other modules must not rely on indirect access to such
>   imported names unless they are an explicitly documented part of the
>   containing module's API, such as os.path or a package's `__init__`
>   module that exposes functionality from submodules.

---

The famous [`requests`](https://github.com/requests/requests/) library has a really nice public interface in my opinion and you could see that it is being done by importing most of things in the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py) file. And you're going to find that it is also documented based on the imports under `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

`from multiprocessing import Process` works because `Process` is imported into the `__init__.py` of the `multiprocessing` package. For example, in your shell, type the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
with open(multiprocessing.__file__, 'r') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

You'll see the lines:

```
from . import context

#
# Copy stuff from default context
#

globals().update((name, getattr(context._default_context, name))
                 for name in context._default_context.__all__)
__all__ = context._default_context.__all__
```

So yes, it's the same thing.